# How to write general django views, where one ListView or DetailView can be used for many models

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, python-3.6

How can I write urls and views that can be used with many models?

Consider I have 3 models in my models.py
Name of models : Bike, Scooty, Mobile

Now for Bike model for generic views we need :

```
1]5 views : ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
2]5 urls : one for each 5 views we need 1 url
3]4 html files are required : 
    bike_list.html : for ListView
    bike_detail.html : for DetailView
    bike_form.html : for CreateView and UpdateView
    conifirm_delete_view.html : for DeleteView
```

Now for Scooty model for generic views we need :

```
1]again 5 views : ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
2]again 5 urls : one for each 5 views we need 1 url
3]4 html files are required : 
    scooty_list.html : for ListView
    scooty_detail.html : for DetailView
    scooty_form.html : for CreateView and UpdateView
    conifirm_delete_view.html : for DeleteView
```

For another model I will need : 5 more view, 5 more urls, 4 more html files.

But if you write general views and pass the name of model in the URL its self and grab that in view and pass it to generic views.

So same 5 views, 5 urls and 4 html files can be used for many models.

Answer (score 1):

Full Code in GitHub Repo

```
https://github.com/punisher21maximum/Blog/tree/master/Minimise_Django_Code
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    #subcat Views
    SubcatListView,
    SubcatDetailView,
    SubcatCreateView,
    SubcatUpdateView,
    SubcatDeleteView,
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #subcat
    path('<str:model>/new/', SubcatCreateView.as_view(), name='subcat-create'),
    path('<str:model>/', SubcatListView.as_view(), name='subcat-list'), 
    path('<str:model>/<int:pk>/', SubcatDetailView.as_view(), name='subcat-detail'), 
    path('<str:model>/<int:pk>/update/', SubcatUpdateView.as_view(), name='subcat-update'),
    path('<str:model>/<int:pk>/delete/', SubcatDeleteView.as_view(), name='subcat-delete'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Bike, Scooty, Bicycle, Mobile
model_dict = {
    "Post":Post, 
    "Bike":Bike, 
    "Scooty":Scooty, 
    "Bicycle":Bicycle, 
    "Mobile":Mobile
    }

#get my fields
def my_get_model_fields(model):
    all_f = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()] 
    rf = ['id', 'date_posted']
    all_f.remove('author')
    for f in all_f: 
        if f in rf or f.endswith('_ptr'):
            all_f.remove(f)
    return all_f

"""subcat view"""
#ListView
class SubcatListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'blog/subcat_list.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3

    """overriding "dispatch" func to set model passed as arg in URL"""
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = model_dict[ kwargs.get('model', None) ]
        return super(SubcatListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    """ "get_queryset" also Required to override model name """
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """override "get_context_data" to pass model_name to subcat_list.html"""
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['class_name'] = self.model._meta.model_name.title() # kwargs.get('model', None) 
        return context

#DetailView
class SubcatDetailView(DetailView):
    """overriding "dispatch" func to set model passed as arg in URL"""

    # template_name = <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'blog/subcat_detail.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = model_dict[ kwargs.get('model', None) ]
        return super(SubcatDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """override "get_context_data" to pass model_name to subcat_list.html"""
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['class_name'] = self.model._meta.model_name.title() # kwargs.get('model', None) 
        return context

#CreateView
class SubcatCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # model = Bike
    
    # fields = my_get_model_fields(Bike)
    template_name = 'blog/subcat_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """check form author and current logged in user is same"""
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """overriding "dispatch" func to set model passed as arg in URL"""
        self.model = model_dict[ kwargs.get('model', None) ]
        return super(SubcatCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        """overriding "get_form_class" func to get fields for model passed in URL"""
        self.fields = my_get_model_fields(model_dict[self.model._meta.model_name.title()])
        return super(SubcatCreateView, self).get_form_class()

#UpdateView
class SubcatUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    template_name = 'blog/subcat_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """overriding "dispatch" func to set model passed as arg in URL"""
        self.model = model_dict[ kwargs.get('model', None) ]
        return super(SubcatUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        """overriding "get_form_class" func to get fields for model passed in URL"""
        self.fields = my_get_model_fields(model_dict[self.model._meta.model_name.title()])
        return super(SubcatUpdateView, self).get_form_class()

#DeleteView
class SubcatDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):

    template_name = 'blog/post_confirm_delete.html'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):#model
        """overriding "dispatch" func to set model passed as arg in URL"""
        self.model = model_dict[ kwargs.get('model', None) ]
        return super(SubcatDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):#class_name
        """override "get_context_data" to pass model_name to subcat_list.html"""
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['class_name'] = self.model._meta.model_name.title() # kwargs.get('model', None) 
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('subcat-list', kwargs={'model':self.model._meta.model_name.title()})
```

subcat_list.html

```
        {% if class_name  == "Bike" %}
          <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'subcat-detail' pk=post.id model='Bike' %}"> 
        {% elif class_name  == "Scooty" %}
          <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'subcat-detail' pk=post.id model='Scooty' %}"> 
        {% elif class_name  == "Mobile" %}
          <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'subcat-detail' pk=post.id model='Mobile' %}"> 
        {% endif %} 
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ post.img1.url }}" height="250px;" alt="First slide"> 
        </a>

        {% if class_name  == "Bike" %}
            {% include "blog/bike_list2.html" %}
        {% elif class_name  == "Scooty" %}
            {% include "blog/scooty_list2.html" %}
        {% elif class_name  == "Mobile" %}
            {% include "blog/mobile_list2.html" %}
        {% endif %}
```

subcat_detail.html

```
     {% if object.author == user %}
      <div>
        <!-- update and delete -->
        {% if class_name  == "Bike" %}
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-update' pk=object.id model='Bike' %}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-delete' pk=object.id model='Bike' %}">Delete</a>
        {% elif class_name  == "Scooty" %}
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-update' pk=object.id model='Scooty' %}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-delete' pk=object.id model='Scooty' %}">Delete</a>            
        {% elif class_name  == "Mobile" %}
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-update' pk=object.id model='Mobile' %}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'subcat-delete' pk=object.id model='Mobile' %}">Delete</a>            
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}



        
        <div style="font-size: 12px;">
            {% if class_name  == "Bike" %}
                {% include "blog/bike_list2.html" %}
            {% elif class_name  == "Scooty" %}
                {% include "blog/scooty_list2.html" %}
            {% elif class_name  == "Mobile" %}
                {% include "blog/mobile_list2.html" %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```